# Youtube Scraper with Php

Tags: php, web-scraping, youtube

I'm a rookie programmer, trying to find his footing in PHP and i currently want to build a You-tube scraper.

This scraper would search You-tube for a key word, say "drop shipping", and return a list of links bearing that keyword in their title.

so far this is what i got:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dropshipping");


$videos = [];
$i = 1;
foreach($html ->find("div.yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video vve-check clearfix") as $video){

      if($i > 10){
        break;
      }

      $videoDetails = $video0->find("a.yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-servicelink spf-link");
      $videoTitle = $videoDetails ->title;
      $videoUrl = "http://youtube.com" . $videoDetails->href;
   echo $videoUrl;

     $videos[] = [

    "title" => $videoTitle,
    "link" => $videoUrl


      ];
      $i++;

}

     echo(sizeof($videos));

?>
```

This keeps outputting zero(0).
Can't figure out why this is. I suspect that the  tag link changes every now and then coz i echoed the html page and analyzed the link, some times you'd have the link class to be "yt-uix-servicelink" other times it would be "yt-uix-sessionlink"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Tried it by your own and show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Scraping is (naturally) forbidden by YouTube terms. If you are interested in _search_ itself, not implementing it by scraping specifically, you can look into using official API for it. Documentation for [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) has examples, including PHP one.

Answer (score 3):

Scraping is (naturally) forbidden by YouTube terms.

If you are interested in *search* itself, not implementing it by scraping specifically, you can look into using official API for it. Documentation for [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) has examples, including PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube pages are loaded dynamically .. not static .. thats why scraping YouTube will not work .. use [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with a YouTube key instead like the other guy said .. there's alot of tutorials on it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).